# Shorewall: DNAT to IPSEC tunnel zone not routing correctly

Tags: debian, iptables, ipsec, ip-routing, shorewall

I have a ipsec tunnel working that gives access to a `192.168.4.0/24` lan. It is working fine and I can access hosts on the other side without problem:

```
# from fw and lan hosts:
# ping 192.168.4.44
PING 192.168.4.44 (192.168.4.44) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.4.44: icmp_req=1 ttl=127 time=4.41 ms
```

but when I try to forward a port on shorewall from the public IP address to a host on the other side of the tunnel, it doesn't routes the traffic:

```
# from wan side:
# telnet x.x.x.x 33901
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
```

`tcpdump` capture on firewall for IP doing the telnet (wan):

```
# tcpdump -n -i eth0.20 host 37.15.173.52
10:09:48.312840 IP [fw_public_ip] > 37.15.173.52: ICMP host [fw_public_ip] unreachable, length 68
```

why shorewall is routing correctly traffic from fw and lan side but not from wan?

---- `shorewall` config ----

relevant `routes` entries:

```
#ACTION   SOURCE DEST                  PROTO      DEST  SOURCE    ORIGINAL
#                                                 PORT  PORT(S)   DEST
DNAT:info wan    vpn:192.168.4.44:3389 tcp        33901 -         [fw_public_ip]
```

relevant `zones` entries:

```
#ZONE   TYPE
wan   ipv4
vpn   ipv4
```

relevant `hosts` entries:

```
#ZONE   HOSTS                            OPTIONS
vpn     eth0.20:192.168.4.0/24,[ipsec_host_ip]   ipsec
```

relevant `tunnels` entries:

```
#TYPE    ZONE  GATEWAY  GATEWAY ZONE
ipsec    wan   [ipsec_host_ip]
```

relevant `interfaces` entries:

```
#ZONE   INTERFACE       BROADCAST       OPTIONS
wan     eth0.20         detect          dhcp,routefilter
```

relevant `masq` entries:

```
#INTERFACE   SOURCE       ADDRESS         PROTO   PORT(S) IPSEC   MARK
eth0.20      0.0.0.0/0    [fw_public_ip]
```